not able understand this behaviour of async programming in Kotlin Coroutines and Flows
 runBlocking{
        val x  = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch{
            println("starting of this scope")
            x.emit(3)
            println("ending of this scope")
        }
        println("parent scope")
        println(x.first())
   }

Output :

parent scope
starting of this scope
ending of this scope
3

runBlocking{
val x  = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null)
launch{
println("starting of this scope")
x.emit(3)
println("ending of this scope")
}
println("parent scope")
println(x.first())
}

Output :

parent scope
null
starting of this scope
ending of this scope

There is difference in only coroutine builder and scope but i got unexpected output?
can anyone please tell me why it is so?

What is your expected behavior and how does it differ from observed results? If we use launch() then two parts of code run concurrently, so we don't get any guarantees on the execution order. We should assume random/arbitrary ordering.

Testing asynchronous behavior of coroutines with runBlocking might confuse you because it uses a single-thread dispatcher which ends up inherited by zero argument launch.
Result of first sample is random (just run it a couple of times, sometimes it returns null instead of 3). Success hinges on the fact that println is somehow heavy operation which gives enough time for new coroutine to start and emit the value.
Meanwhile second one is practically deterministic (there's no multithread race). It runs your block until it reaches a suspension point - but there isn't one so it just keeps running until root of your runBlocking is done, only then dispatcher starts executing launch-ed child coroutines.
If you want your result to be more reliable perhaps you want to actually suspend until it's available by using x.filterNotNull().first().

Second one is deterministic for the current implementation, but still not guaranteed by the coroutines framework. As a rule of thumb, if writing concurrent code, we shouldn't assume any specific execution order if the framework doesn't guarantee it.

only then dispatcher starts executing launch-ed child coroutines.hence same thing can be done in first case scenario? why there is difference can you please explain that?

@AkshatSinghal if you create new CoroutineScope() then coroutines launched in it will use it' dispatcher and not inherit the one from runBlockings scope. It's unclear what "same thing" you want to achieve but you should look into flow filter or job joining when you need to deal with coroutine race.
